# what is minimum requirements for reactjs deployment in production?

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

according w3school.com `https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_getstarted.asp` (React Directly in HTML)
we can load online react babel library

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
```

and running react code without any node js installation.

my question is,is possible developing small react web application only using that without any node js installation in web hosting services?

Comment: It is possible, but I wouldn't recommend it. If you create a React app with [CRA](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app) it will automatically set up a build system (Webpack) for you so that you'll be able to make a production build and you won't require a Node server to host it.

Comment: "without any Node.js installation in web hosting services" if you don't use server side rendering react application compiles down to static files. You can definitely compile it on your dev machine and avoid having node on hosting machine.

Comment: React JS is just a JavaScript library just like JQuery. Backend doesn't matter at all. https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html

Comment: ReactJS is only JS code that generates you VirtualDOM there's no backend stuff here...

Comment: thank for your explanation, it's help. I am litle bit confuse and woried before

Comment: @Jordi Nebot I only rent hosting services that not allow me to install nodejs and other development tool. my development is for research purpose

Comment: That's perfectly ok with what I suggested. All the building will be done in your local development machine and then you just need to deploy the static bundle in whatever hosting service you rented. You could even use platforms like Heroku or Firebase that will allow your tests for free.